# Block access to System classes in class library

Tags: c#, .net

Can anyone recommend a way to block access to particular system classes in a particular assembly?  For example I may want to block FileStream or other I/O classes in a class library that implements a certain layer that shouldn't involve I/O.  It doesn't have to be insurmountable, the point isn't to combat hostile developers, only to reduce layering errors by team members (including myself) and easily identify such code by breaking the compile.

Comment: FYI, the classes you're talking about have nothing to do with C#. They are **.NET** classes, not C# classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you could 'block access'. But you can analyze your codebase as part of the build. The only existing out-of-the-box solution I'm aware of is [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) - it allows you to write explicit rules alike SQL. It is not free though.

Comment: I ended up going with NDepend.  Custom FxCop rule support is very poor at the moment.

Answer (score 6):

Seeing as though it sounds like your trying to "block" *coding practices* as opposed to executed code then I think you should look at FxCop and [writing some custom rules](http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/index.html).

You can then [integrate FxCop into your build process and cause it to "break the build"](http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2009/06/making-sure-fxcop-warnings-and-errors-break-the-build/).

Comment: Didn't know FxCop allows to write custom rules. Thanks for info. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to block I/O, don't worry about blocking individual classes, use [`FileIOPermission`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission.aspx) and block I/O.

Comment: Right, but I'd like to be able to catch more than just file I/O.  Trying to enforce zero I/O in our business logic layer.  Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source of that class library you could just define aliases for everything you want to block... these aliases would point to something "neutral" which throws an exception when accessed...